# JS Checkout: How to handle parent window closed during approval?

Tags: javascript, paypal

We've ran into a weird edge case in our checkout flow where, after we create the order via the API and launch the PayPal window for the user's approval, they are able to escape out of the checkout flow somehow without triggering the `onCancel` callback.

We're contacting some users to figure out exactly how they did this, but we've been able to reproduce it by simply closing the original (parent) window while the PayPal window was still open. As far as we can tell, this or some other very similar situation (like a power failure) is the only way to hit this edge case.

Is there some sort of best practice for handling this situation? Obviously we could have some sort of chron job which looks for old non-accepted/non-canceled orders, but we would prefer some way of addressing them imediately. I've found docs for the `beforeunload` event. Should I just cancel the order with that if the page is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many *potential* situations that can lead to an order not being approved by a payer, such as the power failure you mentioned or a window being left open forever with no action, or a browser crashing. Nothing about your business logic should depend on `onCancel` ever being called.

As for handling such a situation, simply don't capture such PayPal orders. They expire on their own. Your own system's record of the payment attempt / cart order can expire when you want it to.